# How can i show the pagenumber in production

Tags: list-view

Below is my screen

[image: Production]

for this screen not showing the page number selection in production when i open sandbox it
 is showing the page number selection below is my sandbox page what i have to do..in production

[image: Sandbox]

Answer (score 2):

I think the driving factor here is the total number of records in the list. In your sandbox you only have a few records, but in production you have 2000+ records. When the number of records is large the list view doesn't try to count them all and so cannot calculate the total number of pages. You normally do get a page number in the bottom right though; this may be chopped off your screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

In other words, if your list view will show more than 2000+ records, it won't give you the amount of pages (because it won't calculate it) It will just let you know that there are more than 2000 records in that view. If the view has less than 2000 records OR 2000 it will tell you how many records and the amount of pages. Also you can change how many records you can see per page.
If you want to see how many records you have for a specific view with filter criteria you would need to use Reports.
I hope that helps!